# Powershell replace escaped character with character

Tags: regex, powershell

Not sure why the cast to int in the following string replace is failing in Powershell:

```
PS D:\> $b = "\x26"

PS D:\> $b -replace '\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})', [char][int]'0x$1'

Cannot convert value "0x$1" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Could not find any recognizable digits."
At line:1 char:1

+ $b -replace '\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})', [char][int]'0x$1'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

The replace itself works fine:

```
PS D:\> [char][int]($b -replace '\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})', '0x$1')

&
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-replace` operator expects the first string to be the pattern to match and it expects the second argument to be the "string" to replace with.  From the language spec:

```
7.8.4.3 The -replace operator
Description:
The -replace operator allows text replacement in one or more strings designated by 
the left operand using the values designated by the right operand. This operator has 
two variants (§7.8). The right operand has one of the following forms:
•   The string to be located, which may contain regular expressions (§3.16). In this case, the replacement string is implicitly "".
•   An array of 2 objects containing the string to be located, followed by the replacement string.
```

I don't think you can access $1 until the string is evaluated and by then it is too late to do further evaluation i.e. type coercion in this case.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I believe you are correct.  I've come up with an uglier solution to get this done. `while ($b -match '\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}') 
        {
            $b = $b -replace "\$($matches[0])", [char][int]($matches[0] -replace '\\', '0')
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this is a single `-replace`, however you can do it using a custom `MatchEvaluator` callback ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx)).  In the `MatchEvaluator` you have full code control, so you can do whatever crazy stuff you want!

```
$b = "\x26"

$matchEval = { 
  param($m)
  $charCode = $m.Groups[1].Value
  [char][int] "0x$charCode"
 }

 [regex]::Replace($b, '\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})', $matchEval)

>> &
```